# Find, replace in jquery for each element

Tags: jquery

I have this in this var: "ver"
Here i have few lines like this one:

```
<div class="link" id="1"><a ...>Anchor</a></div>
<div class="link" id="2"><a ...>Anchor 2</a></div>
```

I search a code in jquery that turn the above code into:

```
<div class="link" id="1"><a ...><img src="...?anchor=Anchor" /></a></div>
<div class="link" id="1"><a ...><img src="...?anchor=Anchor 2" /></a></div>
```

What i expect from the code: Find each Anchor - Get it - Generate an image that display this anchor.
PS: I have the function for "Image Generating".

SOLVED:

```
$(".link").each(function(){

            anchor =  $(this).find('a').text();
             $(this).find('a').html('<img src="generateLink.php?nr='+encodeURIComponent(anchor)+'" width="39" height="12"/>');  

            });
```

Comment: you cannot have two `id="1"`, hope it's a typo.

Comment: Also ID shouldn't start with a number.

Comment: @jtheman that restriction does not exist in HTML5

Comment: @ExplosionPills Thanks I didn't know. But IF the doctype is HTML4 then he could consider changing it...

Comment: @jtheman ok, but always mention that things before running out with some info. HTML5 is new stuff, and we shouldn't confuse our selves any more.

Comment: @roXon I agree but wasn't aware of this change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the best way to do so is by using a regular expression.

```
jQuery('.link').each(function() {
    jQuery(this).html(
        jQuery(this).html().replace(/<a(.*)>(.*)<\/a>/g,
            '<a $1><img src="..?anchor=$2" /></a>')
    );
});
```

On the first line you tell jQuery to get each element with the class 'link'.
Then you go and find each link inside that element by using '/(.*)</a>/g'.

The first group (a group looks like this: '(.*)') represents the first group we want to capture, because we'll need the
information that element is carrying with it.

The second group is the information we want to store so we know what variable to give our image url.

At the fourth line we'll go and replace what we need. Each $-sign followed by a number is a group we've captured on the third line.

If you want to do some testing on regular expressions I can surely recommend http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Answer (score 0):

If I understood, you must change the line with:

```
$(this).find(a).text().replaceWith(anchor);
```

For

```
$(this).find(a).text(varwithnewcontent);
```

If not, sorry for it!

Comment: Sorry for that... Could you try to explain what you're needing??

Comment: I know what you said but I wrote something wrong in the code.